# Safely terminate finished process in R using foreach package

Tags: r, foreach, parallel-processing, random-forest

I wrote the following script which train a random forest model in parallel using R foreach package, initially I run the training phase in parallel using 20 processors, and the whole process of training is in a nested double for loop, however, I noticed that when the training finishes the 20 processors are still in my cash in a sleeping mode which consumes a lot of memory and I have to kill them manually, since they aren't in use anymore as the results are already saved and a new phase of training is starting from the nested loops, so I was wondering is there a command that can terminate the processes once the results of the trained model is saved: for more clarity on what I want to do the following is my script:

```
library("foreach")
library("randomForest")
library("doSNOW")
for(len in 7:24){ 
   for(clus in 1:3){    
    load(paste("mySCOP_myfull_",paste(len,paste("_Clus_",paste(clus,".RData",sep=""),sep=""),sep=""),sep=""))
    x=as.data.frame(full[,4:(dim(full)[2]-13)])
    y=as.numeric(as.character((as.numeric(as.character(full[,1])))))
    registerDoSNOW(makeCluster(20, type="SOCK"))
    mytr_all = foreach(ntree = rep(25, 20), .combine = combine, .packages = "randomForest") %dopar% randomForest(x, y, ntree = ntree,corr.bias=TRUE,na.action=na.omit)
    outFile=paste("mySCOP_mytr_",paste(len,paste("_Clus_",paste(clus,".RData",sep=""),sep=""),sep=""),sep="")
    save(mytr_all,file=outFile)

    # I want to release the finished "sleeping" processes since reaching here means that the 20 processes finished their tasks and saved the final trained model. in reality the 20 processes are now in the "sleeping mode" which means they are not running but still occupy the cash
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the 'stopCluster' command in the doSNOW package?  You would need to name the cluster to stop it though.  Similar to the following:

```
cluster_name <- makeCluster(20, type="SOCK")
registerDoSNOW(cluster_name)
...
stopCluster(cluster_name)
```

This should work, if I'm understanding the question correctly.